# What is the story behind Lord Varys' box and the prisoner he held there?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

As we know, Lord Varys from *Game of Thrones* was one of the true well-wishers of the seven kingdoms and a brilliant diplomatic person of Kings' Landing.  As per my knowledge he had no relationship with any royal family.

What he actually did for the kingdom made him a member of the council who took important decisions for the kingdom.

But one question, I had seen that he had put some person in the box as a prisoner.  Who was he?  Was Varys torturing him?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the same scene Varys tells Tyrion the story of how he became a Eunuch. He was a slave boy who was purchased by a wizard. The wizard then gelded him as part of some magical ritual and left him for dead. Varys survived and vowed to avenge himself one day. The man in the box is implied to be the wizard that Varys had finally managed to locate.

Comment: How he became member of council?

Comment: @RaviHirani - We don't know the exact circumstance, but we know that it was due to his invaluable skills as a spymaster.

Comment: @RaviHirani That seems to be an entirely different question better asked on its own.

Comment: @Napoleon: I have edited my question.

Comment: @RaviHirani Please do not completely change your question from its original version in a form that entirely invalidates existing answers. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: @Napoleon: okay.  I understood.  I wanted to ask two questions into one but now I will post second question as new question.